# How to reach specific elements by attribute value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Lets say i have this HTML code:

```
<a href="mysite.com" rel="cookie"></a>
<a href="mysite.com" rel="cake"></a>
<a href="mysite.com" rel="cookie"></a>
```

Is there a quick way to select only the 2 **a** tags with the cookie **rel** value.

I did manage to do it using for loop and checking the value on each element, but is there a shorter way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
document.querySelectorAll("a[rel=cookie]");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a JavaScript library, you can use jQuery

```
 var cookies = $('a[rel="cookie"]')
```

more info on jQuery selectors:
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

This has the added benefit of working with older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

For modern browsers use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)

like

```
var els;
if(document.querySelectorAll){
    els = document.querySelectorAll('a[rel="cake"]')
} else {
    //use a loop
}
```